# No component factory found for UserCommonModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, angular6, angular8

I get an error while opening mat model pop am added entry components in associated module but could not solve yet how can we solve give me suggestion pleaseenter image description here

Comment: can you share your full code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `Mat-Dialog` you must include the popup component in `entryComponents` in your `AppModule` file.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ... , UserCommonModalComponent],
    entryComponents: [..., UserCommonModalComponent],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you´re using modals, just put ModalModule.forRoot() in your custom module

Comment: It worked, the bug is not explicit because it requires the addition of entryComponents, which is not correct because it is already done, ModalModule.forRoot() is what was needed in my case.